# I am making a 2d top down shooter and i can't move bullets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Movement mv;
    public GameObject shotPrefab;
    public Transform FirePoint;
    public int direction;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
           
        Rigidbody2D rb =shotPrefab.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
        
        rb.velocity = transform.up * speed*Time.deltaTime;
   
     
    }
    void Shoot()
    {
        Instantiate(shotPrefab, FirePoint.position, FirePoint.rotation);
             
       
    }
```

**This the code of shooting prefab bullet even though the prefab bullet spawns it does move at all I tried other other syntax such as transfrom.translate,rb.Addforce but still no result.**

Answer (score 2):

You must apply the force to the newly instantiated object, not the prefab.

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
        Shoot();
    }
}
void Shoot() {
    GameObject shot = Instantiate(shotPrefab, FirePoint.position, FirePoint.rotation);
    Rigidbody2D rb = shot.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.AddForce(transform.up * speed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: I tried that @Iggy but it didn't work